# Electrifications of quasi-geodesics in relatively hyperbolic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

This post is somewhat of a followup to my previous post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409774/proof-that-lifts-of-geodesics-are-quasi-geodesics-relatively-hyperbolic-groups). $\DeclareMathOperator\Cay{Cay}$Suppose $G$ is a relatively hyperbolic group with peripheral subgroups $P_1,P_2,\dots, P_n$, and suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a finite generating set for $G$. Let $X=\Cay(G,\mathcal{S})$ denote the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $\mathcal{S}$, and let $\hat{X} = \Cay(G,\mathcal{S}\cup \mathcal{P})$ where $\mathcal{P} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} P_i$. As Derek Holt pointed out in my previous post, Antolin and Ciobanu prove that given a geodesic $\gamma$ in $X$, the electrification $\hat{\gamma}$ is a quasigeodesic in $\hat{X}$ without backtracking. This is Lemma 5.3 in the following reference:

*Antolín, Yago; Ciobanu, Laura*, [**Finite generating sets of relatively hyperbolic groups and applications to geodesic languages**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/tran/6701), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 368, No. 11, 7965-8010 (2016). [ZBL1396.20042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1396.20042).

Here, by *electrification* of a path $p$ in $X$ I mean we replace any maximal word in $p$ that is contained in some peripheral $P_i$ with the word in $\hat{X}$ that corresponds to the same word. Essentially, any maximal subpath of $p$ that is contained in a coset is replaced with a single edge in $\hat{X}$ between the same endpoints.

Also, a path has *no backtracking* if it never revisits any coset $gP_i$ that it has already visited.

**My question is the following:** Is it known under what circumstances can we say that the electrification of a quasigeodesic $\gamma$ in $X$ is a quasigeodesic in $\hat{X}$? If it is not always, what properties are needed? For example,

1. What if we knew that $\gamma$ already did not backtrack?
2. What if we knew that $\gamma$ fellow traveled with every quasigeodesic with the same endpoints? (e.g. $\gamma$ is a quasigeodesic between two points in a stable subgroup)?
3. What if both 1 and 2 were true?
4. What if $X$ itself were hyperbolic?
5. Other requirements?